# Why ternary operation return false result?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have custom ternary operation where I get user gender from numbers:

**Code:**

```
$value = 0;
$gender = $value === 0 ? 'Male' : $value === 1 ? 'Female' : 'Other';
echo $gender;
```

In my think this code must return `Male` but return `Female`. [Here](https://3v4l.org/k1fDr) is example.

Or my ternary operation incorrect for getting `Male` result?

My ternary operation not equal with this code?

**Code:**

```
if($value === 0) $gender = 'Male';
elseif($value === 1) $gender = 'Female';
else $gender = 'Other';
```

Comment: Dont know why, but you should add parantheses for else-if ternary like this:
`$value === 0 ? 'Male' : ($value === 1 ? 'Female' : 'Other');`

Answer (score 4):

It's a precedence issue, your code is evaluated as:

```
$gender = ($value === 0 ? 'Male' : $value === 1) ? 'Female' : 'Other';
```

but what you want is:

```
$gender = $value === 0 ? 'Male' : ($value === 1 ? 'Female' : 'Other');
```

This is because PHP evaluates the ternary operator from left to right. See the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: There're tons of duplicates, yet you decided toi create anoter one.

Comment: @u_mulder I tried googling and SO search but can't find it. Can you close it?

Comment: @u_mulder thanks. I have added it to my dupes list. My problem was I only searched for "not working", which brings up a lot of questions which are not the same as this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some brackets, take reference from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

```
<?php

$value = 0;
$gender = $value === 0 ? 'Male' : ($value === 1 ?'Female' : ('Other'));
echo $gender;
```

Check Example: [here](https://3v4l.org/ECldk)